# dotCmis .CreateDocument with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, cmis, dotcmis

Good morning,
i need to create a bunch of documents with Apache chemistry dotcmis. However even in the most trivial case SharePoint triggers a CmisConstraintException when calling folder.CreateDocument. I have tested with all VersioningStates available, but that does not solve the issue. I use dotCmis 0.6. The Alfresco part of my application runs fine, btw..

-Armin

Here's my mock up.

```
using DotCMIS;
using DotCMIS.Client;
using DotCMIS.Client.Impl;
using DotCMIS.Data.Impl;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters;
        parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
        parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://coretwo/" + "websites/migrationtest" + "/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories";
        parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "joe@test.org";
        parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "whoknows";


        var session = SessionFactory.NewInstance().GetRepositories(parameters).Single(r => r.Name.Equals("Dokumente")).CreateSession();
        var rFolder = session.GetRootFolder();


        IDictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        properties[PropertyIds.Name] = "Hello World Document";
        properties[PropertyIds.ObjectTypeId] = "cmis:document";

        byte[] content = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");

        ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStream();
        contentStream.FileName = "hello-world.txt";
        contentStream.MimeType = "text/plain";
        contentStream.Length = content.Length;
        contentStream.Stream = new MemoryStream(content);

        IDocument doc = rFolder.CreateDocument(properties, contentStream, null);  

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Murphy is everywhere...i found the answer minutes after posting here. The trick is to use DotCMIS.Enums.VersioningState.CheckedOut when calling CreateDocument and do the checkin thereafter.

So here is what works for me:

```
IDocument doc = rFolder.CreateDocument(properties, contentStream, DotCMIS.Enums.VersioningState.CheckedOut);
doc.CheckIn(true, null, null, "Checkin", null, null, null);
```